# Flex 4 detect if user presses enter key

Tags: apache-flex, keypress

The secnario is simple if the user presses enter while in the password field, 
I would like to submit the login for for processing.

How can I detect that event from with in the specific text box.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need to worry about keyPress events in this case. `TextInput` conveniently dispatches an [enter](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/TextInput.html#event:enter) event when user presses enter.

```
<mx:TextInput id="passwd" displayAsPassword="true" enter="submit()"/>
```

Script:

```
private function submit():void
{
  var pw:String = passwd.text;
  //submit the login here.
}
```

This is applicable for [spark TextInput](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/TextInput.html?filter_flex=4#event:enter) also.

Comment: If you have a button with your form, an alternative way to do it is also set the "defaultButton" property on your container. When you press the Enter key, it is synonymous to clicking the default button (perhaps "Login" in your example). When doing so, there is no need to listen for the "enter" event nor manually handling event of the KeyboardEvent class.

Answer (score 5):

keyDown="if (event.keyCode==Keyboard.ENTER){ userRequest.send();}"